# Django logout button bootstrap navbar

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I want to add a logout button to my bootstrap navbar but it doesn't look right.

```
{# template.html #}

<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-expand">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">{{ user.get_username }}</a>
        </li>
        <form class="form-inline nav-item" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Log out</button>
        </form>
        {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Log in</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Sign up</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

is there any way to make the button look like a bootstrap `nav-link` ? If not, how do I make it an anchor that will POST to Django's logout endpoint?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#" 
    onClick="document.getElementById('logoutform').submit()">
    Logout
  </a>
</li>
<form id="logoutform" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a form. Simply replace the form with this:

```
<a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
```

Comment: this doesn't actually logout the browser.

Comment: Unless you are wrongly overriding the built-in `LogoutView`, this is enough to logout the user.